# How to make CookieSession active only in certain paths?

Tags: node.js, session, express

I want the session to be active only for certain paths of the application.

1. `/cookieFolder/1` , `/cookieFolder/3` and all its sub-paths should have access to session.
2. `/cookieFolder/2` and all its sub-paths should not have access to session

Currently i have the following code:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:"HELLO", key:"sc", cookie:{path:"/cookieFolder/1", httpOnly:false}  }));
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:"HELLO", key:"sc", cookie:{path:"/cookieFolder/3", httpOnly:false}  }));
....
app.get('/', routes.index);
app.get('/cookieFolder', routes.index);    
app.get('/cookieFolder/1', routes.index);     
app.get('/cookieFolder/2', routes.index);    
app.get('/cookieFolder/3', routes.index);
```

**routes.index**

```
  if(req.session.count){
    req.session.count = req.session.count + 1;
  }else{
    req.session.count = 1;
  }      
  res.render('index', { title: req.session.count });
```

hitting `/cookieFolder/3` increments `req.session.count`. But hitting  `/cookieFolder/1` multiple times, the count session variable stays in `1` for ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the approach slightly. In following line, you are completely override the options

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:"HELLO", key:"sc", cookie:{path:"/cookieFolder/1", httpOnly:false}  }));
app.use(express.cookieSession({secret:"HELLO", key:"sc", cookie:{path:"/cookieFolder/3", httpOnly:false}  }));
```

And In following options object, the value against "path" key tell ExpressJS to set any session to specified path,

```
{
    secret : "HELLO",
    key : "sc",
    cookie : {
        path : "/cookieFolder/3", //All cookies set in this path only
        httpOnly : false
    }
}
```

In detail, Because of specifying explicit path, ExpressJS making set-cookie header as follows,

```
set-cookie: sc=<somesessionid>; path=/cookieFolder/3;...
```

Hence, Browser read the cookie for this path only. In other word, you can only read the any cookie from browser on holding the path "/cookieFolder/3" in address bar.

So I have suggested following things to solve your problem,

1.Let ExpressJS use their default path option by doing as follows,

```
app.use(express.cookieSession({
    secret : "HELLO",
    key : "sc",
    cookie : {
        // path : "/cookieFolder/1", //Remove this line
        // httpOnly : false //Use it as Optional
    }
}));
```

2.Set cookie as follows, By doing this, we can force the browser to send back the cookie as part of request header with specific path only. Hence, You can check whether the cookie available or not on server side.

```
if(/*<some condition 1>*/){
res.cookie('cookiename1', 'cookieValue1', { path: '/cookieFolder/1' });
}    
if(/*<some condition 2>*/){
res.cookie('cookiename3', 'cookieValue3', { path: '/cookieFolder/3' });
}
```

3.Then, You can access the cookie, in above specified routes handler as follows

```
if(!!req.cookies.cookiename){
request.session.count = request.session.count || 0;
request.session.count++;
}
```

**Note:** There is one more way, Just set path specific cookie as `res.cookie('cookiename', 'cookieValue', { path: '/cookieFolder/' });` and then you can skip the path '/cookieFolder/2' in ExpressJS Router Callback later.

Comment: Where should i place the codes in step 2 (Set cookie as follows). What is is for ? i could not understand the use of step 2. Could you explain?

Comment: @rajKamal, I have edited my answer in step2. You can place the code wherever you want in your application. You have to ensure availability of res object(response object). The place could be your router handler as well.